# Why does my code not work when a character is in the second row of the array?

Tags: java

I have some code with a method that is trying to return the opposing character label of a 2d array's position.

Let's suppose the array and it's labels for each position are like below:

```
{{3,3,3,3}, {3,3,3,3}}
  a,b,c,d    e,f,g,h
```

If b is entered, f is returned. I have it working right if a, b, c, or d is entered, but it doesn't work right if e, f, g, or h is entered and I can't figure out why.

```
public class ByteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] testArray = {{3,3,3,3}, {3,3,3,3}};
        //                    a b c d    e f g h
        char slectdPit = 'e';
        int total = (int)slectdPit;
        int total97 = total - 97;
        System.out.println(myGetOpposingPit(slectdPit, testArray));
    }

    public static char myGetOpposingPit(char b, int[][] ints) {
        char retChar = 'z';
        int retVal = 0;
        int charPosi = 0;
        int total97 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ints[0].length; j++) {
                charPosi = (int)b;
                total97 = charPosi - 97;
                if (total97 <= ints[0].length) {
                    if (total97 == j) {
                        retVal = (charPosi + ints[0].length);
                        retChar = (char)retVal;
                    }
                }

                else if (total97 > ints[0].length) {
                    if (total97 == (j + (ints[0].length))) {
                        retVal = (charPosi - ints[0].length);
                        retChar = (char)retVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return retChar;
    }

}
```

I've made an if statement

```
 else if (total97 > ints[0].length) {
                if (total97 == (j + (ints[0].length))) {
                    retVal = (charPosi - ints[0].length);
                    retChar = (char)retVal;
                }
```

That's supposed to get find labels that are in the second row of the array, and assign returnedChar with `characterPosition` - array row length, so if the character ran through `myGetOpposingPit` is g, it'd be `charPosi (103) minus ints[0].length (4), equaling 99`, which gets `ascii` converted into 'c'.

Doesn't work though, `z` gets returned. So one of my if statements isn't running or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems to be incorrect for when `total97 == ints[0].length`. I changed the branch that gets executed when they are equal:

```
public static char myGetOpposingPit(char b, int[][] ints) {
    char retChar = 'z';
    int retVal = 0;
    int charPosi = 0;
    int total97 = 0;

    charPosi = (int)b;
    total97 = charPosi - 97;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < ints[0].length; j++) {

            if (total97 < ints[0].length) {
                if (total97 == j) {
                    retVal = (charPosi + ints[0].length);
                    retChar = (char)retVal;
                }
            } else if (total97 >= ints[0].length) {
                if (total97 == (j + (ints[0].length))) {
                    retVal = (charPosi - ints[0].length);
                    retChar = (char)retVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return retChar;
}
```

I also moved the `total97` assignment out of the loop. It doesn't change so it doesn't need to be calculated each iteration.